# How to hand over credentials with quarkus as main application without application.properties

Tags: quarkus

I have a quarkus application which is a main app. Here is an simplified example:

```
@QuarkusMain
public class MyXYZTool { 

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Quarkus.run(MyXYZTool.class, args);
    }

    public static class CacheApp implements QuarkusApplication {
        @Inject
        AgroalDataSource dataSource;

        @Override
        public int run(String... args) throws Exception {
          

            readCommandLineParameter(args);
            //and so on...
          
            return 0;
        }
    }

};
```

I have also an application.properties which contains the credentials to access to an Azure cloud blobstorage.

```
Secrets.BlobStorages.xyz.ConnectionString=abcaccesstoken
```

I start my app from command line like this:

```
//start from command line
java -jar  ./target/xyz-runner.jar
```

My app works also so far.
But I want to hand over the credentials to access an **Azure cloud blob storage** over the command line. It should not be hardcoded in the application.properties. This has security reasons.

I ask me how I can hand over `Secrets.BlobStorages.xyz.ConnectionString` over the command line and activate this.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score -1):

I have found an answer to my question by this webside from Quarkus:
https://quarkus.io/guides/config#overriding-properties-at-runtime
I tried it out and it works.